# How to implement cross domain request for Office 365 OAuth2 login authentication?

Tags: authentication, .net-core, oauth, azure-active-directory

I have used Office 365 OAuth2 login authentication for an ASP.NET Core API. This is working fine when accessing this API directly from browser. But, when I am calling this API from ajax request / other another web application,  below Cors policy error occurred.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=e0745314-9236-4fr2c-a2fg0-c19cjfsfrrrb6b&scope=api%3A%2F%2Fe0745314-9236-4fr2c-a2fg0-c19cjfsfrrrb6b%2Ftestapi&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A44332%2Fsignin-oidc&state=CfDJ8Kp1w7Ui3OZMswaNrHvqNR2MF9qKa9w3PILEMBv8s_zxSa3sMK1pQLr2EuNexhz8eM6
iDdbO2ciuxInNPCtbO1KJ31O_zXvOA_sMXHbAhzzkXKN9QDmrHMUOiQQdjXjam4EqKlopDpcE2vUxcus
4WehJCUfCqdQZjMuzZS7ovrxslRX2ueRNFqpSDichJCf_iduXgFV1bNLRM8gK0TmjUrdkdYtyji7BNsNdPP
o9Fhad' (redirected from 'https://localhost:44332/api/login/account') **from origin 'null'** has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have tried to fix this issue using the following method in startup file. But, still I get this issue.

ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader();
}));
```

Configure:

```
app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

**Client Application** : http://localhost:5000  
**API** : http://localhost:44332  
**Login provider** : Office 365
```

Please suggest me the standard way to implement cross origin and redirect to respective client application (http://localhost:5000) URL after getting authorization from Office 365?

**Note :** While redirect from API to Microsoft login "origin" become "null".

Answer (score 0):

The server must allow the credentials. To allow cross-origin credentials, call AllowCredentials:

```
services.AddCors(o => o.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", builder =>
{
builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
.AllowAnyMethod()
.AllowAnyHeader()
.AllowCredentials();
}));
```

Comment: I have allowed any credentials too. Still I got this error. Seems my origin become null when redirect to Microsoft login page.